# Convert character Code Set from 1252 to 1256

Tags: c++, oracle, character-encoding, cp1252

I've written a code to check the char code set of the input we're providing. Currently, my system supports Character codeset1252 (WE8MSWIN1252). Is there any chance that I can change the database charcodeset to 1256 (AR8MSWIN1256)? If yes, then how can I change it?

Comment: Using what technology/language/database…?

Comment: @deceze, I'm using C++

Comment: "database charcodeset": Are you using a database? If so, specify which one.

Comment: its oracle database @Codo

Comment: So do you want to reconfigure Oracle to use a different character set, or do you want to convert text from one character set to another (in C++) and then store it in the database?

Comment: I just want to change the charcodeset, I'm fine with anything. @Codo

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your answer. Can you please revisit my question and be more clear?

Comment: @ziya Does this answer your question: stackoverflow.com/q/53171945/18667225 ?